# Unlist column in data frame with listed

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I have a list with multiple levels that I would like to the data level into a data frame, where the variable chr is collapsed into single strings.

```
 myList <- list(total_reach = list(4),
                   data = list(list(reach = 2,
                              chr = list("A", "B", "C"),
                              nr = 3,
                              company = "Company A"),
                   list(reach = 2,
                        chr = list("A", "B", "C"),
                        nr = 3,
                        company = "Company B")))
```

I would like to transform this into a data frame that looks like this:

```
  reach     chr nr   company
1     2 A, B, C  3 Company A
2     2 A, B, C  3 Company B
```

Using dplyr and data.table I've come this far.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(rbindlist(myList[2])) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()

colnames(df) <- names(myList$data[[1]])
rownames(df) <- c(1:nrow(df))

df$chr <- as.character(df$chr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate_all(funs(unlist(.recursive = F, use.names = F)))
```

However, chr column contains strings with "list()" wrapped around it.

```
  reach                 chr nr   company
1     2 list("A", "B", "C")  3 Company A
2     2 list("A", "B", "C")  3 Company B
```

A) Is there a better way to unlist this kind of list and turn it into a data frame? 
B) How do I collapse the lists in chr to strings or factors?

Comment: I guess this `matrix(unlist(myList[-1]), nrow = length(myList), byrow = TRUE)` is too easy...

Comment: @Sotos it splits up the strings (A,B,C) into different columns. I want them gathered in one.

Comment: Perhaps you could give this a try, `df %>% mutate(chr = str_c(chr)) %>% mutate(chr = str_replace_all(chr, pattern = or(fixed("list"), char_class("\""), OPEN_PAREN, CLOSE_PAREN), ""))`. I have used `stringr` and `rebus` packages here.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
myList[-1] %>% 
     map_df(transpose)  %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(c('reach', 'nr', 'company')), funs(unlist))
```

Answer (score 4):

With `data.table` you can try

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(myList$data, as.data.table))[, .(chr = toString(chr)), 
                                              by = .(reach, nr, company)]
```

> ```
>    reach nr   company     chr
> 1:     2  3 Company A A, B, C
> 2:     2  3 Company B A, B, C
> ```

---

Note that there is a difference in using `as.data.table` or `as.data.frame`:

```
rbindlist(lapply(myList$data, as.data.table))
```

> ```
>    reach chr nr   company
> 1:     2   A  3 Company A
> 2:     2   B  3 Company A
> 3:     2   C  3 Company A
> 4:     2   A  3 Company B
> 5:     2   B  3 Company B
> 6:     2   C  3 Company B
> ```

```
rbindlist(lapply(myList$data, as.data.frame))
```

> ```
>    reach chr..A. chr..B. chr..C. nr   company
> 1:     2       A       B       C  3 Company A
> 2:     2       A       B       C  3 Company B
> ```

---

Alternatively, `chr` can be manipulated *before* converting the list into a data.table:

```
rbindlist(lapply(myList$data, function(x) {
    x$chr = toString(x$chr)
    return(as.data.table(x))
}))
```

> ```
>    reach     chr nr   company
> 1:     2 A, B, C  3 Company A
> 2:     2 A, B, C  3 Company B
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `rbind` to put everything together, then I reformat the `chr` column with `sapply`

```
library(magrittr)
myList$data %>%
  do.call(rbind,.) %>%
  transform(chr %<>% sapply(paste,collapse=","))
#   reach   chr nr   company
# 1     2 A,B,C  3 Company A
# 2     2 A,B,C  3 Company B
```

*EDIT a few months later:*

One line longer but a more idiomatic `tidyverse` variation:

```
library(tidyverse)
myList$data %>%
  map_df(as_tibble)    %>%
  group_by(reach,nr,company) %>%
  summarize_at("chr",paste,collapse=",")
```