# How to unlist a data frame column that is a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Suppose I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2))
df$b <- list(NULL, NULL)
```

Note that `sum(is.null(df$b)` is `0` because `b` is a list, not a vector.

How do I get it to be a vector?  Some things I tried that didn't work:

```
# does nothing
df <- df %>% flatten(b)
# removes column b!
df <- df %>% mutate(b=unlist(b))
# destroys df
df <- df %>% unnest(cols=c(b))
# doesn't run
df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars=c('b'), funs(unlist))
```

There are already [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994206/unlist-a-list-within-a-data-frame) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884917/unlist-column-in-data-frame-with-listed) that ask this, but their solutions did not work for me.

I am trying to get through data from `jsonlite`, similar data to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60939570/34935).

Comment: do you expect a data.frame as output or a `b` only vector.  Here, it is not clear about the expected because `c(NULL, NULL)` won't work to be of length 2, it is still a single NULL

Comment: Good question. I want to end up with a dataframe, with `b` as a column.

Comment: If you know `b` is the list column. Wouldn't `df$b <- NA` work?

Comment: @RonakShah I was not super-specific, but some of the NULLs may not be NULL, and I don't want to lose them. I should've had two examples: one all NULLs, one only some NULLs.

Answer (score 3):

Set up data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3))
df$b <- list(NULL, NULL, 4)
```

Unlist:

```
df$d <- unlist(lapply(df$b, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x)))
```

Verify the answer:

```
df
#   a    b  d
# 1 1 NULL NA
# 2 2 NULL NA
# 3 3    4  4

str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3
 $ b:List of 3
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : num 4
 $ d: num  NA NA 4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map` to replace the `NULL` elements with `NA` and then `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(b = map(b, ~ replace(., is.null(.), NA))) %>% 
    unnest(c(b))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#      a b    
#  <dbl> <lgl>
#1     1 NA   
#2     2 NA
```

---

Or a hacky option is

```
df %>%
    mutate(b = coalesce(NA, unlist(b)))
#  a  b
#1 1 NA
#2 2 NA
```

When there are only `NULL` elements, it needs to be converted to other value e.g. `NA` or else it would not work in a `vector`

```
c(NULL, NULL)
#NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the data frame of @Sathish:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3))
df$b <- list(NULL, NULL, 4)
```

code to transform:

```
is.na(df$b) <- lengths(df$b)==0
df$b <- unlist(df$b)

df
  a  b
1 1 NA
2 2 NA
3 3  4
```